# Problem Partitions Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, gparted, partitioning, gpt

I was trying to install a dual boot in my PC (I have Windows 7 Installed Already), it does not recognize my partitions, I even left non allocated space and nothing, it saw it as a free disk. Then i run gparted in Ubuntu live CD an this is what showed me:

```
/dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT Table. However it, does not have a valid fake msdos partition Table, as it should.Perhaps it was corrupted possibly by a program that doesnt understand GPT partition Tables.Or Perhaps you Deleted the GPT table, and are you using ,sdos partition table. Is this a GPT partition Table?
```

And no matter what i respond to that yes/no , it shows me like if i had a blank Drive.

Please help.

This is the result of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xaeb663d7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   221825519   110809336    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       221827072   567169023   172670976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Did you convert a Windows 8 in UEFI to Windows 7 in BIOS boot mode. Windows does not convert correctly and leaves backup gpt partition table. Then Linux tools get confused. But if you have Windows 7 in UEFI boot mode do not do this. You can remove backup gpt table with fix parts. http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/  Also how many partitions do you have MBR(msdos) only allows 4 primary partitions and you must use one as the extended partition.

Comment: Go to a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run: `sudo fdisk -l` and edit your question with the output. (That's lower case -L, not -1). You might have some leftover GPT data that needs to be removed on a MBR formatted disk (see [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/))

Answer (score 0):

Your partition table is damaged, or at least quirky enough for `parted` to not know how to deal with it. It looks like you've probably just got stray GPT data, which is easily removed by `fixparts` (part of the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu). See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html) or [the FixParts documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) for further details.